# Uninstalled old version of rails and now no longer have rails executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, nitrousio

Working in Nitrous.IO, my rails app was acting strange. So I checked and I was using rails version 0.9.5 instead of version 4.0.1! I decided to do a `gem uninstall rails --version 0.9.5`. Everything is good, except it also removed the rails executable! How do I get that back? Seems like version 4.0.1 is there, but I can't run the `rails` command. Should I just uninstall and reinstall rails?

***UPDATE***: Tried `gem install rails` even though I already had rails 4.0.1 installed:

```
action@creativebox-45198:~$ gem install rails                                                                                                                                      
Successfully installed rails-4.0.1                                                                                                                                                 
1 gem installed                                                                                                                                                                    
action@creativebox-45198:~$ rails -v                                                                                                                                               
-bash: rails: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved through Nitrous support channels. Somehow the file `/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails` was missing, and `gem install rails` did not add it. Manually adding this file with the following contents solved the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_noexec_wrapper
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine running `gem install rails`.

Comment: Updated question with this. It installed rails 4.0.1 again I guess, but the `rails` command still doesn't exist :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hash rails` if you're using Bash, or `rehash rails` for csh, at the command-line.

Sometimes the shell loses track of where files are and (re)hash tells the shell to figure it out.

Do a search for `hash + shell` or use `man hash` for more information.